# Rational quadratic form with given determinant and Hasse-Witt invariant

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $Q$ be the diagonal quadratic form  denoted by
$$Q(x_1, \ldots, x_k) = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} d_i x_i^2,  \quad x_i \in \mathbb{Q}, \quad d_i > 0$$

Also let ${\mathbb{Q}^{*}}^2$ be the set of nonzero squares of rational numbers, i.e. ${\mathbb{Q}^{*}}^2 = \{q^2 | q \in \mathbb{Q}, q \ne 0\}$

$V = \{ p | p \text{ is prime}\} \cup \{\infty\} $.

[Hasse-Witt invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_invariant_of_a_quadratic_form) of the $Q$ for any $\nu \in V$ is denoted as
$$E_\nu(Q) = \prod_{i < j} (d_i, d_j)_\nu \in \{\pm 1\},$$ where $(\cdot, \cdot)_\nu$ is the [Hilbert symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol#Hilbert_symbols_over_the_rationals).

It is known that $(a, b)_\nu = 1$ for almost all $\nu \in V$ and $\prod_{\nu \in V} (a, b)_\nu = 1$.

*Is there any algorithm or criteria* to determine if for fixed $k, D, \epsilon_\nu$ there exist $d_1, \ldots, d_k$ such that

1. $det(Q) = d_1 d_2 \ldots d_k \equiv D \mod (\mathbb{Q}^{*})^{2}$
2. for any $\nu \in V$ holds $E_\nu(Q) = \epsilon_\nu$

Comment: The last proposition of Chapter IV in Serre’s *Course in Arithmetic* (before the appendix) answers your question.